# Appengine connected Android Project - Add Account

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I just signed up for 'C2DM' and created an 'Appengine connected 
Android Project'. After starting the Android Project, when I try to add my Account comes an error after the Server Settings: "Unable to open connection to Server". Is this 
error coming up, because my C2DM account hasn't been released yet?

Answer (score 2):

What target are you using?  If you're using the AOSP (Android) 2.2 or above, you need to switch to using the Google API level 8 instead.  This will allow you to use a (required) google account.

Edit: Let me clarify in that it's the emulator that needs to be running Google vs Android target, not the build target of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Google Api 8 Emulator will give no problem. Worked for me.
in Eclipse..
Menu > Windows > Avd Manager > Create a new AVD with google api 8 .
Make sure to change the run configurations of project too...

[image: Scree]