# I am unable to get C2DM messaging to work with code provided by google

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

So,

I have been following along with the Google IO demo for creating an "app engine connected android project" in eclipse. Supposedly when you create a new app engine connected project in eclipse you should have C2DM working 'out of the box'. I used the same google account when creating the project that I used when signing up for C2DM and I used the same package name that I used when signing up as well. I signed up for the account two days ago and got an email that stated that I should be able to start sending messages in 'a day or so'. It's been two days and still no luck.

When I deploy the app to my emulator I select a google account to register with C2DM and get the error message Failed To register/unregister @gmail.com.

Any Suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

C2DM never works out of the box. It's a beta.

Use a dedicated Google account for sending C2DM. Don't reuse your regular one. There are, typically, *two* Google accounts involved in C2DM - the sender account and the account of the phone/emulator user. The latter can be your own. However, when you fire your `c2dm.intent.REGISTER` intent, the "sender" parameter should denote the sender account.

The receiver account's role is minimal, on the other hand. You just need to list it under Accounts in the phone/emulator `Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

If u are failing add an account then try this post
[Appengine connected Android Project - Add Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254073/appengine-connected-android-project-add-account/9532744#9532744)

And if you failing to say hello after the registration then
You will have to make changes to Util.java and change a line there. 
A change in Util.java debugUrl's return statement helped the thing to work.

private static String getDebugUrl(Context context) {

.....
....
..
.

return new String ("http://10.0.2.2:8888"); 
    }

Below is the snapshot of that method..
[image: snapshot of function]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... turns out its related the emulator.

Your emulator must use an AVD with Google API's. The rest is easy.

Hope it helps.